# How to create files and folder in Atom using the command line?

Tags: linux, atom-editor

I was watching a speedy workflow tutorial about Atom text editor, and saw how the guy uses Linu commands like `ls` (to check the files in the directory), `touch` (to create files eg. style.css) and `mkdir` (to create folders). Now in my Atom editor I am able to open the command line using the following command.

```
CTRL + SHIFT + T
```

Now in my command line the default windows command line opens up, I am able to create folder using `mkdir`, but the commands `touch` and `ls` don't work, which makes me wonder weather Atom has its own command line?

See the **[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsykY.jpg)** to see how this guy is creating folders, files and using the ls command.

So my question is, how do I create files in Atom? How do I get the touch command to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the tutorial is using the [Term2 package](https://atom.io/packages/term2) for opening a shell within the editor (http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/speedy-workflows-with-atom/lessons/term2). Since you seem to be able to open a terminal using the described screenshot, you seem to have the Term2 package installed - so far so good.

This package opens a standard command window within the editor. The tutorial seems to be using Linux or Mac OS X as the operating system. If you're running Windows, you will only have the Windows CMD interpreter available.

Windows does not natively support the `touch` command (but it has a `mkdir` command). There is a [unxtools](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) project that provides some of the common Gnu tools. If you install that, you should be able to run `touch` from the Windows command shell as well. More details can be found [here](https://superuser.com/a/764716/119764).